# Why an object scale is not the same when child under another objects ? and how to scale the object to be the same size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The game start when my object name NAVI is child of a crate.  The NAVI scale is set to 0.02 on X Y Z

[image: Navi size]

The parent Crate_0_0 size scale is set to 5 on X Y Z
On the left is the NAVI object on the right the Crate_0_0 inspector scale settings.

[image: Navi and Crate size]

Then after some time in the game I move the NAVI object to be a child of another object :

```
transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent").transform;//rig_f_middle;
 transform.localPosition = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent").transform.localPosition;
 transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
 transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
```

I set here the scale of NAVI to 0.001f on X Y Z the result is that now NAVI is in the hand of the player in the size I want it to be :

The player scale is set to 1 on X Y Z

[image: NAVI under the player hand as child]

And this is a screenshot of the NAVI as child in the player hand :

The scale size of rig_f_middle.02.R is 0.9999999 on X Y Z
The scale of Navi Parent is 1 on X Y Z

The scale of NAVI now is 0.001 on X Y Z

[image: NAVI scale size when NAVI is child in the player hand]

The problem is that if I change the scale of NAVI when he is child of the Carte to 0.001 it will be too small almost will not be see. Even when it set to 0.02 it's too small.

The size I want it to be in both places/cases when it's child of the Carte and child of the player hand is to be the size it looks like when it's in the player hand !

But the scaling is not the same proportion. 0.02 un the carte is too small but 0.02 is bigger then 0.001 and 0.001 is big enough when it's under the player hand.

How can I know or set the scale of NAVI size to be on both places the same as when it's in the player hand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple alternative to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64312558/7111561) would be to adjust the scale before the parenting in world space

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);

var parent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent").transform;
// This will now keep the world scale you gave it before
// but change the "localScale" accordingly in order to basically
// do the calculation internally that was provided in the other answer
transform.parent = parent;
// I also doubt that you want to clone the localPosition here
// If the "Navi Parent" would have a certain offset against its parent 
// then you would be doubling it 
// -> You rather want to copy the absolute position
transform.position = parent.position;
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Vector3 targetScale; // The final world scale you want

Vector3 parentScale = navi.transform.parent.lossyScale;
navi.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
        targetScale.x / parentScale.x,
        targetScale.y / parentScale.y,
        targetScale.z / parentScale.z);
```